# Unable to set custom resolution through xrandr

Tags: nvidia, display, xrandr, display-resolution

So I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my mac through duel booting, and I was unable to choose my monitors native resolution (1920x1080). After looking around a bit I found I could do it using xrandr, but I ended up getting this error:

```
Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
Serial number of failed request:  29
Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

I got that after doing this line:

```
xrandr --addmode DP-1 1920x1080_60.00
```

If it helps, this is what I get after doing `xrandr` when I have set it as a new mode:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+
   1280x960       60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       85.0     75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        85.1     75.0     72.2  
   640x480        85.0     59.9  
   1920x1080_60.00 (0x281)  173.0MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew    0 clock   67.2KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock   60.0Hz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and generate the modeline with

```
cvt [width] [height] [hz]
```

Then create the mode with

```
xrandr --newmode [part of modeline after word Modeline]
```

And finally select it with

```
xrandr --addmode [newmode]
```

Apologies if you already did all this, it was not obvious from what you posted.

Comment: Yeah, I did all of that before hand. Sorry for not including it in my post